# a doesn't show href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to click on icon and With some api I need to download a file. So I do in my html:

```
<td>
                    <a title="download" ng-show="file.name"
                        class="no-decoration active-download"
                        ng-attr-href="{{ download(file.id) }}" target="_blank" ><i
                            alt="Download" class="fa fa-download fa-2x"></i></a>
                </td>
```

in my javascrip I do
//in init

```
$scope.download= download;

function download(id) {
        console.log("LINK");
        console.log(id)
            console.log(urlDownloadAllegatoDettRend)
        var link = urlDownloadAllegatoDettRend + '?id=' + id;
        return link;
    }
```

The problem the  doesn't contain the link to download file. I tried another solution with `ng-href`:

```
<td>
                    <a title="download" ng-show="file.name"
                        class="no-decoration active-download"
                        ng-href="{{ download(file.id) }}" target="_blank" ><i
                            alt="Download" class="fa fa-download fa-2x"></i></a>
                </td>
```

But it seems doesn't work.Anyone can help me?

Comment: You're logging, what's the console output?

Comment: yeah . when I inspect my element I don't see the href in <a>

Comment: What is `urlDownloadAllegatoDettRend`? Is this variable accessible by `f : download(id)` ?

Comment: url to get file download

Comment: is not empty doesn't worry. It is equals to "..../dwnload_file"

Comment: Yeah but can the `download` function actually read that variable? What happens if you store it as a local variable within the download function (just for now as a test)?

Comment: You can test by trying `ng-href="{{!!download(file.id) ? download(file.id) : '/'}}` -- this should get the `href` attributes to appear because it will resolve a value for it if `download(id)` falls over.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make sure that the `download(id)` function is working properly.

Let's add an expression that will show us if the function is returning a value (the fact that the `href` isn't appearing is pretty much telling us that it isn't anyway, but just to be sure):

```
<a title="download" ng-show="file.name"
   class="no-decoration active-download"
   target="_blank" 
   ng-href="{{!!download(file.id) ? download(file.id) : '/'}}">
  <i alt="Download" class="fa fa-download fa-2x"></i>
</a>
```

This ternary expression will just set the `href` attribute to '/' whenever the `download` function returns nothing.

Now that we've hopefully established that it's not working, let's look at the `download` function:

```
function download (id) {

    console.log("LINK");
    console.log(id);
    console.log(urlDownloadAllegatoDettRend);

    var link = urlDownloadAllegatoDettRend + '?id=' + id;

    return link;

}
```

My first suspicion would be that `urlDownloadAllegatoDettRend` is out of scope i.e. the `download` function can't access it.

You can test whether this is the problem by simply hard-coding it as a string instead of referring to the variable:

```
function download (id) {

  var link = "..../dwnload_file?id=" + id;

  console.log("LINK:", id);

  return link;

}
```

If that starts working, you know the `download` function is simply falling over because the variable `urlDownloadAllegatoDettRend` it's trying to read is out of scope and since there's no global variable of that name, it's undefined.

Make the variable accessible to the `download` function and the problem should be solved.

If it still doesn't work right, the problem lies elsewhere. Next thing to look at would be to make sure that `file.id` is actually coming through to the `download` function as the `id` parameter it's expecting.